# Need to Transform JSON using JOLT transformation to specific JSON

Tags: json, jolt

I have below user input json.
[
{
"correlationId": "12345",
"payloadFormat": "Money",
"payload": {
"DE61": "000001000150084063368",
"location": "south",
"name": "Dallas",
"pop": "2M"
}
},
{
"correlationId": "ed1e3",
"payloadFormat": "Cash",
"payload": {
"DE": "000001000150084063368",
"location": "west",
"name": "LosAngeles",
"pop": "4M"
}
}
]

I need to convert in below output with the help of JOLT Spec

[
{
"correlationId": "12345",
"payloadFormat": "Money",
"DE61SF1": "00",
"DE61SF2": "100015008",
"DE61SF3": "4063368",
"location": "south",
"name": "Dallas",
"pop": "2M"
},
{
"correlationId": "ed1e3",
"payloadFormat": "Cash",
"DE61SF1": "00",
"DE61SF2": "100015008",
"DE61SF3": "4063368",
"location": "west",
"name": "LosAngeles",
"pop": "4M"
}
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this spec,

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "&",
        // Shift all the DE nodes to a same named node.
        // Here it is moved as TMPDE
        "payload": {
          "DE|DE61": "&2.payload.TMPDE"
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "payload": {
          "DE61SF1": "=substring(@(1,TMPDE), 2, 4)",
          "DE61SF2": "=substring(@(1,TMPDE), 5, 14)",
          "DE61SF3": "=substring(@(1,TMPDE), 14, 21)"
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "correlationId": "[&1].correlationId",
        "payloadFormat": "[&1].payloadFormat",
        "payload": {
          "DE61SF1": "[&2].DE61SF1",
          "DE61SF2": "[&2].DE61SF2",
          "DE61SF3": "[&2].DE61SF3",
          "location": "[&2].location",
          "pop": "[&2].pop",
          "name": "[&2].name"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks A Lot Jagadesh for this quick help